# How to initialize Python Slackbot module?

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

I'm new to Slack bots (familiar with Discord.py). I am using the Slackbot package (https://github.com/lins05/slackbot) to create my Python slack bot.

Followed the example on their page, installed the package using `pip install slackbot`, went to the path of the installation, created a `slackbot_settings.py` (with specified tags they mentioned) and `run.py` in the main directory and `mybot.py` (with example commands they showed on their page to test), but I can't initialize the bot. I tried to run the bot using python `run.py` but get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 23, in
main()
File "run.py", line 20, in main
bot.run()
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slackbot/bot.py", line 32, in run
self._plugins.init_plugins()
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slackbot/manager.py", line 31, in init_plugins
self._load_plugins(plugin)
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/slackbot/manager.py", line 47, in _load_plugins
path_name = importlib_find(plugin)
File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/importlib/util.py", line 89, in find_spec
return _find_spec(fullname, parent.path)
AttributeError: module 'mybot' has no attribute 'path'
```

`mybot.py` has the following lines:

```
from slackbot.bot import respond_to
from slackbot.bot import listen_to
import re

@respond_to('hi', re.IGNORECASE)
def hi(message):
    message.reply('I can understand hi or HI!')
    # react with thumb up emoji
    message.react('+1')

@respond_to('I love you')
def love(message):
    message.reply('I love you too!')

@listen_to('Can someone help me?')
def help(message):
    # Message is replied to the sender (prefixed with @user)
    message.reply('Yes, I can!')

    # Message is sent on the channel
    message.send('I can help everybody!')

    # Start a thread on the original message
    message.reply("Here's a threaded reply", in_thread=True)
```

Where am I going wrong? I've tried asking the developer but got no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bot apparently can not find your mybot plugin. Assuming `mybot.py` is in the same folder than `run.py` change the entry in `PLUGINS` to `'mybot'`. Then it should work.

Full example of `slackbot_settings.py`:

```
DEFAULT_REPLY = "Sorry but I didn't understand you"

PLUGINS = [    
    'mybot' 
]
```